# Why does my viewer not display anything?

Tags: preview

I am looking to put equations into Keynote presentations, and all of the reading and tutorials I have viewed all tell me to do the same thing: Type up an equation, and drag and drop.

But, there is one main issue: *Nothing I input will typeset!*

I input an equation, click the "LaTex It!" button, a thinking wheel appears in the viewer section for a second, then goes away and nothing appears. Input commands generate no visible equation, nor does simple text. Nothing I put in the editor appears in the viewer.

Solutions I have tried:

- Restarting the program
- Restarting the computer
- Inputing the exact equation keystrokes other tutorials have shown
- Updating my current version
- Installing patches for my current version
- Completely deleting the program and reinstalling a downloaded version

To date, nothing has yielded any results. Does anyone know what is causing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've no idea what Keynote is and how this is connected to LaTeX and friends.

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but are you writing the equations in LaTeXiT? Have you installed MacTeX as well, or just LaTeXit?

Comment: Originally I had the entire MacTex package installed. LaTexit gave me the problem of not compiling my equations. When I deleted and reinstalled, I put only the LaTexit program back on my computer. I saw no change. So then I decided to delete it again, and re-download the entire MacTex package a second time. After repeated testing, there is still no change.